# How to prevent patch from creating backup files?

Tags: patch

I'm writing some code that will apply the patch(1) program, and I want to completely prevent it from creating backup files.  That is, I don't want it to create `foo.orig` files when it either fails to update a particular file (in which case it creates a `foo.rej` file), or when it successfully updates a file but there's some fuzziness involved, both of which it ordinarily does.  This seems to be easier said than done.

Base case: I run "patch" against a Debian source directory, and it fails to update the `debian/changelog` file.  patch creates a file `debian/changelog.orig` file (which is what I'm trying to avoid).

The documentation mentions a `--no-backup-if-mismatch` switch, which seems to be just what I need.  But when I add it, the backup file is still created, only now it's called `debian/changelog.~1~`.

The documentation also says that when the `--posix` switch is present, backups will not be made.  When I use this switch in place of `--no-backup-if-mismatch`, the backup file is still created, but with the original `.orig` suffix.

The only workaround I've found is to use the `-B/--prefix` switch to direct backups to be written to a directory of my choice.  But this seems like an ugly hack.  Isn't there a cleaner way to prevent backups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently `-B/--prefix` is the only way to go.

Answer (score 3):

According to [(diffutils)Backups](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Backups.html), `--no-backup-if-mismatch` does what you want.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the undocumented `--version-control none` option. That option is [documented for the FreeBSD variant of `patch`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=patch).